# Is there a way to store a new Agent property with LotusScript?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Folks,

I've got an Agent in Notes using Lotusscript that asks for a directory each time it's invoked. I'd like to store the directory selection so that it doesn't have to be prompted for each time, simply confirmed. But how do I go about storing a permanent reference I can pick up the next time the Agent runs?

Thanks,

KWL

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking, but I think a profile document is what you need.

Follow these steps to create the form, which should include a field that contains the value you want to retrieve (for this example we'll call it 'directory') : http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/3728634e68f9ca4685256c54004b6c32?OpenDocument

You can access it in your LotusScript function using the NotesDocument class, eg.

```
dim s as New NotesSession
dim db as NotesDatabase
dim doc as NotesDocument
dim directory as String

Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
set doc = db.GetProfileDocument("DocumentName")
directory = doc.GetItemValue("directory")(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the directory selection in an environment string

session.setEnvironmentVar(variablename, value)

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/ceadd0dc386adcbd8525642e00770300?OpenDocument

session.getEnvironmentString(variablename)

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/a2790570da801d6c8525642e0075cdd9?OpenDocument